# Do I need to do a Bonferonni correction on a 2x2 chi square analysis?

Tags: spss, chi-squared

I'm really hoping someone here can help.

I have performed a chi-square test of independence, looking at men/women and early/late drop out from therapy.  I have a p-value of 0.047.  Do I need to do any post hoc testing on this?  Men drop out almost 50:50 early:late whereas women drop out almost 25:75 early:late. Do I need post hoc testing for this and a Bonferonni correction, or is the answer simply:

The frequency of retention rates was compared across gender, finding a significant interaction (X2 (1) = 3.94, p = 0.047), indicating that females were more likely to be retained past the third CBT session than men.

Any help would be greatly appreciated, stats hurt my head and I can't continue past this problem.

Comment: welcome to Stack-Overflow! Please note - this site is for programming questions, while you are asking rather a statistical question. You should post it [here](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/ask) instead.

Answer (score 0):

Since there's only one test performed, with a single degree of freedom, there's no way (or need) to do any multiple comparison correction.